# MUI Menu Item with href component not acting as a link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

So here, I set the href="/" in the Menu Item like so:

```
export const MenuComponent = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const menuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  return (
    <Box>
      <IconButton onClick={(e) => setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget)}>
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={menuOpen}
        onClose={(e) => setAnchorEl(null)}
      >
        <MenuItem href="/">Inicio</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I've defined my link behavior and button base component as so:

```
import Link from "next/link";

const LinkBehavior = forwardRef(function LinkBehaviour(
  props: { href: URL; children: ReactNode },
  ref: Ref<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined
) {
  // I can see the props here.
  const { children, ...other } = props;
  return (
    <Link ref={ref} {...other}>
      {children}
    </Link>
  );
});

const baseConfiguration = {
  components: {
    MuiLink: {
      defaultProps: {
        component: LinkBehavior,
      } as LinkProps,
    },
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        LinkComponent: LinkBehavior,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Now the thing is that I can see that MenuItem is a MuiButtonBase. With that said, it's not linking me anywhere. I can see also that the LinkBehavior isn't called when the menu opens. I can also see that LinkBehavior is called everywhere else a button + href combo gets rendered.

I am using "@mui/material": "^5.10.8", and nextjs 13.2.4.

I tried adding Link component (both MUI and nextjs's Link) like so:

```
<MenuItem LinkComponent={Link} href="/">
          Inicio
</MenuItem>
```

Edit:

I can also see that the menu item is an "li" component instead of an "a" in my dom.

Edit two:

So if I check the type it comes out as `import MenuItem: ExtendedButtonBase<MenuItemTypeMap<{},"li">>`. Almost as if never can be an "a" tag.
If I do the following:

```
<MenuItem onClick={closeMenu} component={LinkBehavior}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Home />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>Inicio </ListItemText>
          </MenuItem>
```

The MenuItem rendered does become an "a" tag. Though, I get in my ts

```
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?: Partial<MenuItemClasses> | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableGutters?: boolean | undefined; divider?: boolean | undefined; selected?: boolean | undefined; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; onClick: () => void; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<{ href: string; } & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?: Partial<MenuItemClasses> | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; ... 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?: Partial<MenuItemClasses> | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; ... 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<{ href: string; } & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; onClick: () => void; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<{ href: string; } & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<{ href: string; } & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; } & { ...; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
      Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<{ href: string; } & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; } & { ...; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<MenuItemTypeMap<{}, "li">>>): Element | null', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; onClick: () => void; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<{ href: string; } & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?: Partial<MenuItemClasses> | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; ... 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?: Partial<MenuItemClasses> | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; ... 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.ts(2769)
```

Last edit:

It's because I had both href and onClick on the same component like this:

```
<MenuItem onClick={closeMenu} href="/" component={LinkBehavior as any}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Home />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>{t("home")}</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
```

Please ignore the previous question; it was ill-formed.

Comment: It looks like it is working as expected [Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-ychmbv?file=pages%2F_app.js,pages%2Findex.js). The first item in the sample code is a link and when I click on it, it takes me to the correct link. What is it that your are expecting?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to respond. The edits didn't show because `<a>` and `<li>` means something in markdown. Anyways, I fixed those errors and added more debugging information.

Comment: Looks like some TS configuration issue. Would it be possible for you to create a reproducible example on Stackblitz?

Comment: Hi will do! Going on vacation and will be back in a week and a half.

Comment: Figured it out. I was wrong and included 'href' and 'onClick' on the same component.

Comment: That was a 8 month long vacation. I wish I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because I had both href and onClick on the same component like this:

```
<MenuItem onClick={closeMenu} href="/" component={LinkBehavior as any}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Home />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>{t("home")}</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
```